# Get a custom error message, instead of 500

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a service that looks like this:

```java
public String storeTestRequest(Map<String, String> data, HttpSession session) {
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(data);

    boolean hasHealthInsurance = json.getAsString("hasHealthInsurance").equals("true");

    try {
        this.testRequestRepository.save(new TestRequest(
                json.getAsString("firstname"),
                json.getAsString("surname"),
                json.getAsString("street"),
                hasHealthInsurance             
        ));
        return "All good.";
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        return "Something went wrong.";
    }
}
```

In this example, I am saving the values of 4 fields but in fact there are much more and I don't want to validate any of them. So if all values could be saved successfully, I should get the message *All good*. But if some values are missing, I should get the message *Something went wrong.*.

I have tried it with try & catch but I still get a 500 error.

Comment: What is the error in the logs

Comment: First of all, you should not get 500 if something bad happens in `testRequestRepository.save` method. Can you share a sample `data`?

Comment: @YJR _java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "String.equals(Object)" because the return value of "net.minidev.json.JSONObject.getAsString(String)" is null_

Comment: @Reem, that show go into the question.  Use the handy [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73802528/edit) link immediately below it to make that so.

Comment: @Moshi data could be for instance `{ "firstname": "x", "surname": "y" }`. I would get a 500 error, because the other values are missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `hasHealthInsurance` property is empty or null. Your exception message says it's caused by this line.

```
boolean hasHealthInsurance = json.getAsString("hasHealthInsurance").equals("true");
```

If you put this line in your try catch block, you will see the exception message in the catch block.

Comment: The exception message does not say so *directly*.  But indeed, if the exception is thrown from the method presented, then that is the only logical conclusion.

Comment: Oh that was a stupid mistake. But it works great. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @JohnBollinger The exception message directly says this. Because there is no `String.equals()` control elsewhere.

Comment: @fatih, the exception message presented by the OP affords the possibility that the exception does not come from the method presented by the OP at all.  It does not include the file or line number (though presumably the actual stack trace does), and it does not quote the source line.  So no, the message presented by the OP does not directly say what you claim it does.  Yours is almost certainly the correct *conclusion* based on the evidence, but that's not the same thing.